# Penetration testing in an unsuitable environment

Tags: python, socket

There are good penetration testing tools in the market in which we can perform various activities gather information from the hosts effectively. But those tools are not helpful always like if we are using some public computers we need administrative rights to install wireshark,social engineering toolkit etc., and at those times hacking cannot be performed.

This script is programmed using Python which will be available on all linux flavors like Ubuntu, Debian, etc., and entirely programmed using native libraries

This tool has various servers and clients which can act according to several requirements.

**MAIN.py**

```
# SWAMI KARUPPASWAMI THUNNAI

#####################################################################################################
# The Networker - The NetWork Knife
#
#$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

import sys
import socket
from clients import Clients
from servers import Servers


def display():
    print("=============================>Networker Ver 1.0<===========================")
    print()
    print("-c => client")
    print("-s => server")
    print("-TCP => establish a TCP client or server")
    print("-UDP => establish a UDP client or server")
    print("--basic => Basic type of server of client which sends and receives the packets")
    print("--type=cat => Bit advanced to the --basic mode")

def about():
    print("""=============================>Networker Ver 1.0<===========================
 Networker the Network Bozooka
 Programmed by Visweswaran
 Product of India
 A standard all in 1 tool for performing pen-testing in an environment where other packages failed
 Do not worry if other tools aren't there now for you got a Bazooka with you""")


clients = Clients()
servers = Servers()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connections = sys.argv
    if "--about" in connections[1]:
        display()
    if "-c" in connections[1]:
        if "--basic" in connections[2]:
            if "-TCP" in connections[3]:
                clients.tcp_basic(connections[4],int(connections[5]))
            elif "-UDP" in connections[3]:
                clients.udp_basic(connections[4],int(connections[5]))
    elif "-s" in connections[1]:
        if "--basic" in connections[2]:
            if "-TCP" in connections[3]:
                servers.tcp_basic(connections[4],int(connections[5]))
            elif "-UDP" in connections[3]:
                servers.udp_basic(connections[4],int(connections[5]))
            else:
                print("[*] NetWorker Report: This is not a valid server name")
        elif "--type=cat" in connections[2]:
            servers.tcp_cat(connections[3],int(connections[4]))
        else:
            pass


    else:
        pass
```

**Servers.py**

```
# SWAMI KARUPPASWAMI THUNNAI
import socket
from threading import Thread

def handle_client(client,type):
    if type==0:
        receive = client.recv(1024)
        print("[*] Received message from client: %s"%str(receive))
    else:
        receive = client.recvfrom(1024)
        print("[*] Received message from client: "%str(receive))
    if type==0:
        print("[*] Bazooka is on TCP mode")
        client.send(b"You just connected to NetWorkers Server")
    else:
        print("[*] Bazooka is on UDP mode")
        client.send(b"you've just connected to networker's server")
    client.close()

def handle_client_wolf(client,type,location):
    x = open(location,"rb")
    file = x.readlines()
    if type==0:
        receive = client.recv(1024)
        print("[*] Received message from client: %s"%str(receive))
    else:
        receive = client.recvfrom(1024)
        print("[*] Received message from client: %s"%str(receive))
    if type==0:
        print("[*] Bazooka is on TCP mode")
        for i in file:
            client.send(i)
    else:
        print("[*] Bazooka is on UDP mode")
        client.send(b"you've just connected to networker's server")
    client.close()
def handle_client_wolf_save(client,type):
    if type==0:
        receive = client.recv(1024)
        print("[*] Received message from client: %s"%str(receive))
        file = open("logs.txt","a")
        file.write("\n")
        file.write(str(receive))
        file.close()
    client.close()
def handle_client_wolf_send(client,type):
    if type==0:
        msg = input("[*] Message : \n")
        client.send(msg.encode("UTF-8"))
        receive = client.recv(1024)
        print("[*] Received message from client: %s"%str(receive))
    client.close()

class Servers:
    def tcp_basic(self,listen_on,listen_port):
        print("[*] NetWorker - The Network Bazooka Basic TCP server")
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server.bind((listen_on,listen_port))
        server.listen(5)
        print("[*] server is listening on %s:%d" %(listen_on,listen_port))
        while True:
            client,addr = server.accept()
            print("[*] Accepted connection from %s %d"%(addr[0],addr[1]))
            client_handler = Thread(target=handle_client,args=(client,0,))
            client_handler.start()
    def udp_basic(self,listen_on,listen_port):
        print("[*] NetWorker - The Network Bazooka Basic UDP server")
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        server.sendto(b"You have attempted to connect to Netoworker's UDP server",(listen_on,listen_port))
        server.bind((listen_on,listen_port))
    def tcp_cat(self,listen_on,listen_port):
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server.bind((listen_on,listen_port))
        print("""
        =========================>NetWorker - The NetWork Bazooka's NetWolf<==========================
        Commands:
        --index to display an html file
        --inform to send some packets
        --save  saves the message sent by the client into a file
        """)
        option = input("Your Option: ")
        server.listen(5)
        if "--index" in option:
            location = input("Enter the location of the file")
            while True:
                client,addr = server.accept()
                print("[*] Accepted connection from %s %d"%(addr[0],addr[1]))
                client_handler = Thread(target=handle_client_wolf,args=(client,0,location,))
                client_handler.start()
        if "--save" in option:
            print("Output will be saved in logs.txt")
            while True:
                client,addr = server.accept()
                print("[*] Accepted connection from %s %d"%(addr[0],addr[1]))
                client_handler = Thread(target=handle_client_wolf_save,args=(client,0,))
                client_handler.start()
        if "--inform" in option:
            print("[*] Packets sending session - Bazooka is ready waiting for a connection")
            while True:
                client,addr = server.accept()
                print("[*] Accepted connection from %s %d"%(addr[0],addr[1]))
                client_handler = Thread(target=handle_client_wolf_send,args=(client,0,))
                client_handler.start()
```

**Clients.py**

```
# SWAMI KARUPPASWAMI THUNNAI
import socket

class Clients:
    def tcp_basic(self,host,port):
        print("[*] NetWorker report: creating sockets to establish a connection")
        try:
            client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            print("[*] NetWorker report: sockets have been created")
        except socket.error:
            print("[*] NetWorker report: failed to create sockets")
        try:
            print("[*] NetWorker report: Connecting to the server")
            client.connect((host,port))
            print("[*] NetWorker report: Connection established!")
        except:
            print("[*] NetWorker report: failed to connect to the server")
        data = input("[*] NetWorker report: Enter the data to be sent => ")
        try:
           print("[*] NetWorker report: sending packets please wait...")
           client.send(data.encode("UTF-8"))
           print("[*] NetWorker report: sent the data! receiving response from the server")
        except socket.error:
            print("[*] NetWorker report: packets sending failed")
        print(client.recv(4096))



    def udp_basic(self,host,port):
        print("[*] NetWorker report: creating sockets to establish a connection")
        try:
            client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            print("[*] NetWorker report: sockets have been created")
        except socket.error:
            print("[*] NetWorker report: failed to create sockets")
        data = ("[*] NetWorker report: Enter the data to be sent => ")
        try:
           print("[*] NetWorker report: sending packets please wait...")
           client.sendto(data.encode("UTF-8"),(host,port))
           print("[*] NetWorker report: sent the data! receiving response from the server")
        except socket.error:
            print("[*] NetWorker report: packets sending failed")
        print(client.recvfrom(4096))
```

**CREDENTIAL HARVESTER ATTACK FIRED FROM THIS SERVER**

Any web page can be displayed I displayed a sample. This code is still improving and I need your suggestions.

Comment: Everything is programmed using native libraries so that pen-testing can be performed in an environment where Python is only available. Python is available in almost all Linux version,  standalone exe is made for windows

Comment: Obligatory warning: If you are trying to pentest in an environment where these kinds of tools are locked away from standard users you may be opening yourself to a legal can of worms by trying to circumvent the locks by implementing your own methods to do this. This (pen testing) is also illegal in some jurisdictions. (Just had to make this point - carry on, all!)

Comment: @ThomasWard sir, I dont get what you are saying since English is not my native you mean it is illegal? Pen-Testing is legal so does this tool it is in the hands of the one who is using it

Comment: I am making a point that in *some countries, cities, states, and regions* penetration testing is actually *illegal*.  Whether that's the case or not for your region is irrelevant, my warning was that you are attempting to do this on a system where you could not use existing tools - which means they don't want to give you that type of access, which means you are circumventing restrictions put into place.  In some countries/states/cities/regions *that* action is illegal.  It's just a note, it doesn't impact anyone's ability to review your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should have a look a [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html), which should make your argument parsing a lot easier and more fail-safe (it quits if the wrong options have been passed, for example.)

```
import sys
import socket
import argparse

from clients import clients
from servers import servers

about = """=============================>Networker Ver 1.0<===========================
 Networker the Network Bozooka
 Programmed by Visweswaran
 Product of India
 A standard all in 1 tool for performing pen-testing in an environment where other packages failed
 Do not worry if other tools aren't there now for you got a Bazooka with you"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=about)
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='mode', help="client or server mode")
    parser.add_argument('port', help="which port to use")
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--protocol', choices=["UDP", "TCP"], default="TCP", help="protocol to use (default: TCP)")

    server_parser = subparsers.add_parser("server")
    server_parser.add_argument('-t', '--type', choices=["basic", "cat"], default="basic", help="type of server (default: basic)")

    client_parser = subparsers.add_parser("client")
    client_parser.add_argument('host')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.mode == 'client':
        client = clients[args.protocol](args.host, args.port)
    elif args.mode == 'server':
        server = servers[args.protocol](args.port, args.type)
```

This parser can be used e.g. like this:

```
$ ./networker.py client 127.0.0.1 80
$ ./networker.py -p UDP client 127.0.0.1 80
$ ./networker.py --protocol UDP --type cat server 8080
$ ./networker.py server 80 -pUDP
$ ./networker.py -p UDP server 8080 -tcat
$ ./networker.py --help
$ ./networker.py client -h
```

---

I will start with the `Clients` class. Right now, there is no need at all for a class here. But there could be one, when making the TCP client and the UDP client two different instances of a Client (or actually instances of sub-classes):

```
import socket

class Client:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host, self.port = host, port
        self.client = self.connect()

    def connect(self, host, port):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def send(self, data=None):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def log(self, message):
        print("[*] NetWorker report: {}".format(messsage))


class TCPClient(Client):
    def connect(self):
        self.log("creating sockets to establish a connection")
        try:
            client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.log("sockets have been created")
        except socket.error:
            self.log("failed to create sockets")
            raise
        try:
            self.log("Connecting to the server")
            client.connect((self.host, self.port))
            self.log("Connection established!")
        except Exception:
            self.log("failed to connect to the server")
            raise
        return client

    def send(self, data=None):
        data = data or input("[*] NetWorker report: Enter the data to be sent => ")
        try:
           self.log("sending packets please wait...")
           self.client.send(data.encode("UTF-8"))
           self.log("sent the data! receiving response from the server")
        except socket.error:
            self.log("packets sending failed")
            raise
        return self.client.recv(4096)


class UDPClient(Client):
    def connect(self):
        self.log("creating sockets to establish a connection")
        try:
            client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            self.log("sockets have been created")
        except socket.error:
            self.log("failed to create sockets")
            raise
        return client

    def send(self, data=None):
        data = data or input("[*] NetWorker report: Enter the data to be sent => ")
        try:
           self.log("sending packets please wait...")
           self.client.sendto(data.encode("UTF-8"), (self.host, self.port))
           self.log("sent the data! receiving response from the server")
        except socket.error:
            self.log("packets sending failed")
            raise
        return self.client.recvfrom(4096)

clients = {"TCP": TCPClient, "UDP": UDPClient}
```

Here I created two classes, one for each connection type. They have different `connect` and `send` implementations. They both return what the receive at the end of `send`. They also do not go on after an error is raised, but re-raise it. This is because after the connection failed, the sending of data will surely also fail. You can change that to do an early return or whatever, but you will still have to handle the error better than just logging it.

I added a `log` function that takes away part of your repetition in printing.

I also added spaces in parameter lists, like PEP8, Python's official style-guide, suggests and fixed a missing `input` for the udp connection.

The `Servers` can use a similar treatment, but I will leave this for another time or another reviewer.

Usage of `Clients`:

```
tcp_client = TCPClient("127.0.0.1", "80")
return_value = tcp_client.send()
print(return_value)

udp_client = UDPClient("127.0.0.1", "80")
return_value = udp_client.send("Hi")
print(return_value)

client = clients["TCP"]("127.0.0.1", "80")
print(client.send("hello world!"))
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your valuable solutions and the link to argparse It is really helpful to me. I am a long time windows user so I have had not opportunity to use command line arguments